# lua bindings for bullet

Tags: lua, swig, bullet

are there any lua bindings for libbullet?

tried using swig and simply `%include`ing the BulletDynamicsCommon.h:

```
%module ybullet 
%{
  #include <btBulletDynamicsCommon.h>
%}
%include "%BULLET_inc_path%/btBulletDynamicsCommon.h"
```

but that doesn't work, as it also just includes other files, which is ignored by swig:

```
ybullet/helloWorld.lua:4: attempt to call field 'btDbvtBroadphase' (a nil value)
```

my lua file is ported from http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Hello_World

Answer (score 0):

found out a way using swig and a zsh script to automagically extract the `%include`s from the header files to get this: https://github.com/nonchip/YEngine/blob/master/ybullet/ybullet.i.tpl